# Western Digital My Passport doesn’t show up on My Computer

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

As the title suggests, my WD external hard disk doesn’t show up on My Computer in Windows 7. Yesterday it worked perfectly but today it doesn’t. I plugged in the hard disk and the light is blinking but the computer doesn't detect the hard disk.

**EDIT**: Problem found. I think so my laptop provides low voltage to power up the hard drive. It works perfectly on the USB port on other side.

Comment: do you have another computer to plug it into?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: @Keltari It works on my friends computer. Yes. Tried restarting but nothing changes.

Comment: same problem... how you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the SATA to USB adapter built into the unit malfunctioned. This has happened to me twice and I no longer buy external USB drives because of it.

To check whether the hard drive still works but the adapter is broken, you will need to take the enclosure apart and install the hard drive inside into your PC or hook it up to a SATA to USB adapter that you know works.

If you haven't already, try plugging your unit in to another PC first to verify it is the unit and not the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the external USB Western digitals are encrypted by chip on the PCB board inside of enclosure and connect them VIA SATA is useless. If your enclosure is broken, you have to use PCB board from any WD enclosures with identical encryption chip, but in case, if your SATA drive doesn’t have any problems. It is just for 3.5" HDDs. For USB WD 2.5” is different story.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this similar issue with a USB thumb drive. In my case, the drive was listed in device manager and I encountered an error related to a process being stuck in memory.

First, check if the device is in device manager, if it is, un-install it, reconnect it and allow the drivers to be installed from scratch and see if this resolves your issue.

**I would have added this as a comment if I was able to

Answer (score -1):

Plug in the WD Passport and open [Disk Management](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm), then right-click the disk and choose `Online` (opposite of my screenshot below).

I've had this specific issue when I try connecting like 4 USB flash and/or hard drives.

[image]

Comment: The WD doesn't appear on Disk Management.

Comment: even it doesnt appear for me as well...